# Bootstrap 3.0 Button in Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I upgraded bootstrap 3.0 now. And "a" tag which looks like btn (by the help of class .btn) is ruined on navbar.

```
<li>
   <a href="<?php echo BASE_PATH; ?>register.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
       <?php echo "<strong>" . _('Bayilik Başvurusu') . "</strong>"; ?>
   </a>
</li>
```

But it is not working correctly. Bootstrap changed the system i think.

Comment: You really should have a look at the Bootstrap 2 to 3 migration section of the documentation.  It lists all the classes that have changed or been removed and what to use in their place.  http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Wrap a `<p class="navbar-btn">` around the `<a class="btn">`:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <p class="navbar-btn">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">I'm a link button!</a>
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lachlan/398kj/

Screenshot:
[image: Bootstrap link button in navbar]

Comment: Thanks, works good and i like your solution better as you are still able to use <a>

Comment: Be warned: the collapsed version doesn't look great. Other links are blocks (i.e. full-width is clickable). If you use `btn-block` it aligns the text centrally, so it doesn't match  other links.

Answer (score 46):

Now, bootstrap 3 has buttons in the navbar like this:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign in</button>`

It uses `navbar-btn` so it knows it's in the navbar.

If you want it to work, do this:

```
<li>
    <form action="#">
        <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Link</button>
    </form>
</li>
```

This way, it still acts like an anchor tag. Just change `#` for the value you actually want it to go to.

So for this instance:

```
<li>
    <form action="<?php echo BASE_PATH; ?>register.php">
        <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Link</button>
    </form>
</li>
```

Comment: what about ? <a type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Link</a> Before we can do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this way if the path it points to is `/app` the result url is `/app?` (note the extra question mark).

Answer (score 24):

With bootstrap 3, it is still possible to have a `<a>`link rendered as a button, but you have to include them into a `<form>`. Also, the `<a>` should include the `navbar-btn` class.

```
<li>
  <form>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm navbar-btn">
      register
    </a>
  </form>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually I found `<div>` works as well, instead of `<form>` which is not semantic. The key is not to make `a` a direct child of `<li>`.

Comment: Is the hover messed up in when you do this, though?  The background for the button goes transparent for me.

Comment: The <div> solution works for me. It's a shame that this is supported natively in the framework though, I've also seen plenty of discussions on Github around it and don't think they have any plans to make links buttons work natively, which to me seems a bad choice.

Answer (score 21):

The problem is that the selector for styling an anchor in a navbar is: `.nav > li > a` which means it has a higher precedence than a .navbar-btn.

You can fix by just wrapping it in another tag like a span. I don't think you should use a form tag as others suggest as it's not a form at all.

Comment: definitely the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://learnangular2.com/events/

EVENT OBJECT

To capture the event object, pass $event as a parameter in the event callback from the template:

```
<button (click)="clicked($event)"></button>
```

This is an easy way to modify the event, such as calling preventDefault:

```
@Component(...)
class MyComponent {
  clicked(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: This... uhm. What?